# Textfield returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

```
 _textfield.text = [_arrayswipe valueForKey:@"username"];
```

I'm getting null value for `textField` when I print it. I have created a `IBOutlet` for it and called. I have seen many other stack overflow pages but couldn't solve it. Its still returning null. Stuck with this problem.

Comment: You have to connect the outlet to the actual text field in your storyboard.

Comment: your array has value [_arrayswipe valueForKey:@"username"]

Comment: I have double checked with that

Comment: yes when i printed it separately  [_arrayswipe valueForKey:@"username"]  it was returning values.

Comment: before assign just print your _arrayswipe and just update your question . because this kind of issue i never face so .

Comment: im getting the value for _swipearray but still im getting (null) for textField.text

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: IBOutlets are assigned values after ViewDidload is called. Iboutlets are nill if views is not presented/pushed.

Comment: where you called this line _textfield.text = [_arrayswipe valueForKey:@"username"];

Comment: Actually i have passed this array when moving to another viewcontroller. I have passed wit using a function                                                                                -(void)dataFromController:(NSMutableArray *)data{
 _arrayswipe=data;                                                                                                                                                                      _textfield.text = [_arrayswipe valueForKey:@"username"];}

Comment: try using `objectForKey:`

Comment: im using nsmutablearray so  objectForKey can't be used

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains any object, then access the value of variable throught object

e.g

```
NSString *userName = [arrayswipe.yourObject valueForKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: my array is not an issue , here textfield is returning null.When i assign a static value for and log it, it still shows null .

Comment: If your are creating a IBOutlet of TextField then delete from nib file and and new one and make a proper connection